# VS 2017 and Docker: Operation aborted

Tags: docker, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

[.Net Core 2 came out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/), so I updated Visual Studio 2017 (Community) to release 15.3.0 (and subsequently 15.3.2) which has support for Docker which I've installed on my machine (Windows 10), and I believe I've configured things correctly.

I created a basic Web API project—on .NET Core 2.0 without Docker—and that works. Now I add Docker support and I can't get it to run! I get the following error:

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio: Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))]

**How do I debug this?** The only other [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613403/1680677) I found wasn't helpful. If you recognize the error, do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue. I found this [forum post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102371/cannot-start-docker-debug-with-vs2017-1532-profess.html) which suggests the fix is either:

1. Reset the credentials on the shared drive settings for Docker
2. Delete the [stale] microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 image and pull the latest again from DockerHub

The first suggestion did not work for me, but the second did.  I probably didn't need to do this, but I also nuked my existing containers and images for the project I was working on.

The Visual Studio build process with Docker support enabled will automatically pull microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 if the image is not found locally.  So, it's easiest to remove the cached image and let the build process pull it down for you.

In order to see local images, from the command line:

```
docker images
```

If you see microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0, then remove the image from your local cache:

```
docker rmi microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
```

After that, when you next build... all is good again.

Comment: 3. On update do not forget to change the core version in  docker-compose.ci.build.yml.  This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but aspnetcore 1.1 and I couldn't check the shared drive in Docker-Settings (Issue 579: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/579). I reinstalled Docker and now it works like a charm.